# Reaching my Pi with MDNS (Avahi)

Tags: connection, headless

I want to ssh into my Pi and I can do it right now with the ip address of the Pi. But I want to do it using mDNS. I want to connect using `ssh raspberrypi.local`. I read that this should work. on the pi, the avahi-deamon is running:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service avahi-daemon status
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-28 12:01:52 CEST; 35min ago
 Main PID: 326 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─326 avahi-daemon: running [raspberrypi.local]
           └─379 avahi-daemon: chroot helper

Sep 28 12:31:21 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 28 12:31:21 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Withdrawing address record for 10.42.0.56 on eth0.
Sep 28 12:31:21 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.42.0.56.
Sep 28 12:31:21 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 28 12:31:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::a3a0:c51a:4fa:5bd0.
Sep 28 12:31:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 28 12:31:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Registering new address record for fe80::a3a0:c51a:4fa:5bd0 on eth0.*.
Sep 28 12:31:45 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.42.0.56.
Sep 28 12:31:45 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep 28 12:31:45 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[326]: Registering new address record for 10.42.0.56 on eth0.IPv4.
```

The hostname is also raspberrypi so that is not the issue. I think the issue might be in my linux system I use to connect to the pi?

If I try to connect this is the error:

```
➜  ~ ssh raspberrypi.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
```

`avahi-browse -arp` and `avahi-resolve-host-name` both also do not work.

My linux system is Fedora 32. I have checked that Avahi is running (same command as on the pi).

I connected the raspberry pi with an ethernet cable to my computer (which is using WiFi). I am sharing my WiFi to my Pi by setting the wired connection to "Shared to other computers" (with both IPv4 and IPv6).

Here is the avahi config on the pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf 
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

[server]
#host-name=foo
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
#allow-interfaces=eth0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
#rlimit-core=0
#rlimit-data=8388608
#rlimit-fsize=0
#rlimit-nofile=768
#rlimit-stack=8388608
#rlimit-nproc=3
```

I am not sure why my system is not able to find the Pi... If you need any more information, I'll be glad to provide!

Comment: What is the ip address and netmask of the device where try to connect to the RasPi?

Comment: seems like mdns/avahi works by default on bookworm even in the minimal distribution

Answer (score 4):

In the avahi.conf:

```
#allow-interfaces=eth0
```

Needs to have the # removed, restart the avahi service, and that fixed it for me.

Comment: `allow-interfaces` defaults to all local interfaces except loopback and point-to-point ([ref](https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi-daemon.conf)) so this shouldn't make any difference. But in any case the output from `service avahi-daemon status` will show you which interfaces avahi is using.

Comment: @kthy I found your response helpful and "service avahi-daemon status" showed me I had an error while the daemon was running. "avahi-daemon[445]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services." I did two things, uncommented "allow-interfaces=eth0" and added modified and uncommented "host-name=raspberrypi".  Thanks!

Comment: I also had to modify "enable-wide-area=no" for the error messages to go away. Track the output of the service with "sudo journalctl -fu avahi-daemon.service" which will tail the log for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have to amend the config file for the GNU Name Service Switch at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to include `mdns4_minimal` when resolving domain names.

In my case (Ubuntu 20.04 + KDE):

- I had this: `hosts:          files dns`
- I changed it to: `hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal`

After the change above I was able to do `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and successfully log into my Raspberry Pi without using a dynamic IP (e.g. something assigned via DHCP by the router to my Raspberry Pi).

See for reference:

- here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration
- here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457166/can-not-resolve-local-domains-internal-to-my-office-lan

Comment: I unfortunately already have mdns4_minimal in my conf file. However, I have fixed the issue by connecting my pi directly to my router instead of sharing WiFi through an ethernet cable with the pi.

Answer (score 1):

For avahi-daemon to broadcast the presence of a device on the network you need to tell it to publish something.

change: `publish-workstation=no` to `publish-workstation=yes`
then:

```
systemctl avahi-daemon restart
```

Comment: `publish-workstation=yes` just registers a service of type `_workstation._tcp` on the local LAN ([ref](https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi-daemon.conf)). What you need is actually `publish-domain=yes` which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You have been over thinking this and/or confused by posts about [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

From most OS (with the exception of some Windows) you can resolve the name `raspberrypi.local` e.g with `ping raspberrypi.local`.

To connect via `ssh` you need to use the correct commands e.g. `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` for a normal *Raspberry Pi OS*.

NOTE Occasionally this will fail, due to caching in the network, but this is unusual.

Comment: The ping and ssh both do not work as I said... I accidentally forgot the user indeed for the ssh but it doesn’t change anything sadly.